# How can I pass the initial state of a reducer to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have this action

`cancellations.js`

```
const toggleCheckboxAction = id => ({
  type: ActionTypes.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX,
  payload: id,
});
```

And this reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  checkboxes: [
    {
      labelText: '...'
      checked: true,
      value: 'itemsCancelled',
      id: 'checkBoxItemsCancelled',
    },
    {
      labelText: '...'
      checked: true,
      value: 'requestDate',
      id: 'checkboxRequestDate',
    },
    {
      labelText: '...'
      checked: true,
      value: 'status',
      id: 'checkboxStatus',
    },
    {
      labelText: '...'
      checked: true,
      value: 'requestedBy',
      id: 'checkboxRequestedBy',
    },
  ],
}

[ActionTypes.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX](state = initialState.checkboxes, action = {}) {
    return state.map(checkbox => {
      if (checkbox.id !== action.payload.id) {
        return checkbox;
      }
      return {
        ...checkbox,
        checked: !checkbox.checked,
      };
    });
  },
```

And I have this component where I need to use that action/reducer.

```
import React from 'react';
import connect from 'react-redux/es/connect/connect';
import { Checkbox } from 'carbon-components-react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { toggleCheckboxAction } from '../actions/cancellations';

    const CheckboxList = ({ checkboxes, dispatch }) =>
      // This checkboxes array is what I need to get from the reducer
      checkboxes.map(checkbox => (
        <Checkbox
          key={checkbox.id}
          id={checkbox.id}
          labelText={checkbox.labelText}
          value={checkbox.value}
          checked={checkbox.checked}
          onChange={() => {
            dispatch(toggleCheckboxAction(checkbox.id));
          }}
        />
      ));

    CheckboxList.propTypes = {
      toggleCheckboxesHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    export default compose(
      connect(
        // I guess here I have to do the connection logic
      ),
    )(CheckboxList);
```

Right now I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Which comes from `checkboxes.map(checkbox => (...)` in the component above.

Do you have an idea how to initialize my component with that array coming from the reducer?

I don't know if I can use something like `mapStateToProps` maybe

Comment: Have you initialised your redux store correctly - and added the reducer to the root reducer?

Comment: @dwjohnston yes. All of that is done. All I need is to pass what I have to that component I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you post your full root reducer? what you've got there doesn't look complete. (It ends with a comma? )

Comment: @dwjohnston all of that is done. And yes, it ends with a comma. That's the way the linter it's been set up.

Comment: I can't see that that would be working. That `[ActionTypes.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX](state =...)` is not valid syntax that I know of. (correct me if I'm wrong!)Can you show me where you are getting that from?

Comment: @dwjohnston here is some of the code but I can't adapt that to the code I posted above => https://codesandbox.io/s/zrm2mvnqmx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set up the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

[Here are the relevant docs.](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

You want to do someething like this: (long form):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps)=>( {
     checkboxes : state[ActionTypes.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX]
}) ;

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps
  ),
)(CheckboxList);
```

Comment: This is confusing. Where should I place that `mapStateToProps`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: With your component, just like you have done. `mapStateToProps` is a function that accepts state (the redux state) and ownProps (the react components own props), it returns some props to add to the react component.

Comment: Here is some of the code but I can't adapt that to the code I posted above => https://codesandbox.io/s/zrm2mvnqmx

Comment: @Reacting - I mean - what you've got there looks like it is working. I put the labels on it: https://codesandbox.io/s/07o2020rn

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a little bit of logic necessary to get this working. You need to include `mapToStateProps` at the end of your code and connect it.

**How to use `mapToStateProps`**

After this:

```
CheckboxList.propTypes = {
      toggleCheckboxesHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };
```

place this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //whatever you are bringing over
  //example auth: state.auth 
});
```

And connect it like this:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { toggleCheckboxesHandler }
)(CheckboxList);
```

Together, after your render method your code should look something like this:

```
CheckboxList.propTypes = {
          toggleCheckboxesHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        };
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      //whatever you are bringing over
      //example auth: state.auth 
 });
 export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { toggleCheckboxesHandler }
    )(CheckboxList);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, what I need to bring on mapStateToProps is `initialState.checkboxes` is an array which you could see on my reducer. Let me try your code.

Comment: try doing checks: state.checks, then log your props to your console and see if you see a checks obj with a checkbox array...makes sense?

Comment: so instead of where i have the "whatever your are bringing over" put `checks: state.checks` then at the top of your render method or wherever do `console.log(this.props) and see if you see an obj in your console

Comment: How can I console log the props if I am using a stateless component?

Comment: oh shittake mushrooms :) face palm i'm sorry. im a little sleepy over here :) okay you can test it by making it into state component and turning it back...or you can do this.props.checks.checkbox.map and see if anything is rendered

Comment: I can not get it working. Here is my code in more detail https://codesandbox.io/s/14kzz2vmlj it is not working but you could take a look.

Comment: I am getting this error: -> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkboxId' of undefined`

Comment: okay let me take a look. no worries. we will figure this out :)

Comment: do you have database by any chance? if not maybe set up another action that actually saves your initial state data. I've always worked with data coming from the database or local storage. I've never seen someone place data into their intiial state in their reducer. but that's just me. if you're set on doing it that way maybe someone else who is more familiar with that method can provide more assistance...i'm sorry :(